# ¿Como ejecutar un script .py en android?

Tags: android, python, python-3.7, qpython

Tengo un formulario sencillo para registrar información, lo tengo en un script en .py, y requiero ejecutarlo en un dispositivo android. No sé si se pueda ejecutar como .py, o si es mejor en .exe.

Muchas gracias, quedo atento a cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Android no ejecuta archivos *.exe*, ni ninguna distribución ... puedes ejecutar el script *.py*, pero si lo vas a ejecutar desde Android tiene que ser desde el *IDE* que mencionaste(qpython)

Comment: Además de *QPython* puedes utilizar *Termux*, que viene a ser un *Linux para Android* de un solo usuario. Puedes conectarte con SSH para utilizarlo desde un PC. Para mi *Termux* tiene muchas ventajas, aunque con él no podrías desplegar interfaces gráficas si es lo que buscas. Un saludo.